# Is space reserved for a field when data doesn't use the full length?

Tags: sql-server, storage, database-internals

A column is marked as `nvarchar(50)`, but the value stored is only two characters. Do the remaining 48 characters take up space?

Answer (score 3):

NVarchar does eat up more space per character used, but you don't take up the space for unused characters like you would with CHAR.  That's the beauty of the Var portion.

So NVarchar is 2x (bytes) the actual length, plus 2 bytes at the end.  Therefore in fields where you MIGHT have some very long characters but usually don't, this would work well as it guarantees space for the long string, but doesn't eat as much space as it would if you were to reserve it with CHAR.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/char-and-varchar-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16

> char [ ( n ) ]
> Fixed-size string data. n defines the string size in bytes and must be a value from 1 through 8,000. For single-byte encoding character sets such as Latin, the storage size is n bytes and the number of characters that can be stored is also n. For multibyte encoding character sets, the storage size is still n bytes but the number of characters that can be stored may be smaller than n. The ISO synonym for char is character. For more information on character sets, see Single-Byte and Multibyte Character Sets.
>
> varchar [ ( n | max ) ] Variable-size string data. Use n to define the
> string size in bytes and can be a value from 1 through 8,000, or use
> max to indicate a column constraint size up to a maximum storage of
> 2^31-1 bytes (2 GB). For single-byte encoding character sets such as
> Latin, the storage size is n bytes + 2 bytes and the number of
> characters that can be stored is also n. For multibyte encoding
> character sets, the storage size is still n bytes + 2 bytes but the
> number of characters that can be stored may be smaller than n. The ISO
> synonyms for varchar are charvarying or charactervarying. For more
> information on character sets, see Single-Byte and Multibyte Character
> Sets.

Comment: Note CHAR, and NCHAR only store the padding if the table is uncompressed.

Comment: @DavidBrowne-Microsoft Or sparse, or column store.

Answer (score -1):

**`nvarchar`** is *variable-length* only **reserve** space for the characters you store. It doesn't reserve storage like `nchar` which is *fixed-length*  **reserve** storage space for number of characters you specify even if you don't use up all that space.

**Note:** `nchar` and **`nvarchar`** takes up twice as much storage space than `char`  characters **`nvarchar`** , so it would be good to use them only if you need *Unicode characters*.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).